# How to load Material-UI icons without includes or JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am writing a Rust library to use React/Material-UI. For this reason, I need to call React APIs from code without using JSX. For Material-UI components, I am using its [CDN version](https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@1.3.1/umd/material-ui.development.js). It doesn't depend on node.js and doesn't use `require` commands. But I cannot find a similar library to include Material-UI icons. The libraries available online are for use with node.js (using `require`).

Comment: By `include` do you mean `import` ? Nothing to do with node.js if so

Comment: I mean `require` (I updated the question), like in `var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");`